# Why am I getting IllegalMonitorStateException?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I get the following Exception being thrown when I try to unlock an object.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(Unknown Source)
    at Pipe.unlock(Pipe.java:21)
    at Station.doWork(Station.java:81)
    at Station.run(Station.java:66)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

All that Pipe.unlock is doing is the following:

```
public void unlock(){
   accessLock.unlock();
}
```

Where accessLock is an ReentrantLock

Do you know where the issue could be?

EDIT:

This is the run method in Station

```
if(Pipes[inConnection].accessLock.tryLock()){
    System.out.println("Station "+ StationNumber+": granted access to pipe "+inConnection+".");

//This is just a way for me to keep track if both pipes have been granted
            if(connected<0)
                connected=inConnection;
            else
                connected+=inConnection;
}


if(Pipes[outConnection].accessLock.tryLock()){
            System.out.println("Station "+ StationNumber+": granted access to pipe "+outConnection+".");

    //This is just a way for me to keep track if both pipes have been granted
    if(connected<0)
        connected=outConnection;
    else
        connected+=outConnection;   
}


        doWork();
```

While this is the doWork method:

```
private void doWork() {
    if(connected==inConnection+outConnection){
        System.out.println("Station "+StationNumber+": successfully flows "+inConnection+".");
        System.out.println("Station "+StationNumber+": successfully flows "+outConnection+".");

        Pipes[inConnection].unlock();
        System.out.println("Station "+StationNumber+": released access to pipe "+inConnection+".");

        Pipes[outConnection].unlock();
        System.out.println("Station "+StationNumber+": released access to pipe "+outConnection+".");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(200));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WorkLoad--;
    }else if(connected >=0 ){
        Pipes[connected].unlock();
        System.out.println("Station "+StationNumber+": released access to pipe "+connected);

    }

    connected=-1;
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to post full code / SSCCE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock%28%29) is pretty clear:

> If the current thread is the holder of this lock then the hold count is decremented. If the hold count is now zero then the lock is released. If the current thread is not the holder of this lock then `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown.

So the thread which is trying to unlock isn't the holder of the lock. We can't tell why you *expected* it to be the same thread without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I've added the two sections that relate to that code. 
The part that confuses me is that it should in fact be holding the lock, so I don't know why....

Comment: @KelseyAbreu: Both of your `if` conditions may be `false`, in which case your thread doesn't own the lock - so you can't unlock it.

Comment: That's why I had the if(connected >=0) where I have a global variable set to -1 whenever neither of the if statement have been true. So in the doWork method, they will only unlock if the connected value has changed. which only happens if either of the if statements are true in the run method.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu: Hmm - I'm finding your code somewhat tricky to understand, to be honest. But you should debug through, perhaps adding some logging to see what's going on. It's not really clear what those three variables (`inConnection`, `outConnection` and `connected`) are meant to be. You should also look at *which* of your three `unlock` calls is throwing the exception.

Comment: Yea decided to do that. Seems to always be the second one. The Pipes[outConnection].unlock(). Looking to see why now

Comment: @KelseyAbreu: Right. So it sounds like either the value of `outConnection` is changing, or you've got something else going on - as I say, I find your various connection variables hard to understand as they are. (It's not clear why you'd want to add indexes to another, for example.)

Comment: It's a piping system. Where one pipe is the inPipe and the other is the outPipe. One station cannot use a pipe if another is already using it. And I think I found the error, had to do with bad logic.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is more than a year old, but I was facing the same problem and the solution turned out to be not another Thread that was holding the Lock somehow but basically a very simple mistake and the inner details of a ReentrantLock. If we look at the implementation of tryRelease:

```
protected final boolean tryRelease(int releases) {
  int c = getState() - releases;
  if (Thread.currentThread() != getExclusiveOwnerThread())
     throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
  ..
  if (c == 0) {
    ..
    setExclusiveOwnerThread(null);
  }
  ..
}
```

If the release-count drops to zero, the exclusiveOwnerThread is set to null. And if you afterwards try to release the lock once more, you're not the exclusiveOwnerThread anymore, since your Thread is unlikely to be null. So one simple .unlock() too much can lead to this (in this situation rather confusing) Exception.

Comment: well dug in but.. how do we avoid to call unlock() if .hasLock() returns true? There are no public methods to check this release counter or currentThread != ownerThread

`if(UI.getCurrent().getSession().hasLock()) {
                UI.getCurrent().getSession().getLockInstance().unlock();
            }`

Comment: Casting lock doesn't help either.
`ReentrantLock rLock = (ReentrantLock) 
UI.getCurrent().getSession().getLockInstance();
                if (rLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) { //here current and owner are ==
rLock.unlock(); // here != hahahah
                }`

Comment: I suppose it means you have to keep track on your own. That's basically what I did after I found out why it crashed, so you cannot just "unlock again, just to make sure". Easiest way to do that is to design your code in a way that you lock and unlock it just once, and not as part of a loop or something like that.